# Calculate how long a contact is inactive

Tags: workflow, formula-field

I have had a mental block.

Aim- calculate how long a contact has been inactive

This is so simple ,but for the life of me I can't think how to do it.

Field :Inactive 
Data type : checkbox

Looking forward to your response

Many thanks

Comment: You need some sort of date or datetime stamp of when the inactive box was checked, and then you can simply subtract from today to get time passed.

Comment: Hi sfdc , thanks for the swift response. Is there anyway I can calculate the date from contacts who are already inactive ?

Comment: Not if you didnt store the date or datetime that they became inactive.  you need to have the data in order to calculate

Comment: If the inactive field was used in field history anyway I can reference that via api , then populate the newly created date field ?

Comment: yes, if it was being tracked and you want to query it, then yes, you could use that